# How to use the hint by the author? (Problem 3-23 in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Problem 3-23.
> Let $C\subset A\times B$ be a set of content $0$. Let $A'\subset A$ be the set of all $x\in A$ such that $\{y\in B:(x,y)\in C\}$ is *not* of content $0$. Show that $A'$ is a set of measure $0$. *Hint:* $\chi_C$ is integrable and $\int_{A\times B}\chi_C=\int_A\mathcal{U}=\int_A\mathcal{L}$, so $\int_A\mathcal{U}-\mathcal{L}=0$.

---

> Problem 3-15.
> Show that if $C$ has content $0$, then $C\subset A$ for some closed rectangle $A$ and $C$ is Jordan-measurable and $\int_A\chi_C=0$.

---

> Problem 3-18.
> If $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is non-negative and $\int_A f=0$, show that $\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}$ has measure $0$.

---

I solved Problem 3-23, but I'm not confident in the accuracy of my solution because I didn't use the hint provided by the author.

So, I want to know if my solution is right and I want to know how to use the hint by the author.

My solution:

By Problem 3-15 and Fubini's Theorem, $\int_{A\times B} \chi_C=\int_A\left(\mathbf{U}\int_B\chi_C(x,y)dy\right)dx=0$.
By Problem 3-18, $\{x\in A:\mathbf{U}\int_B\chi_C(x,y)dy\neq 0\}$ has measure $0$.
Let $D_x=\{y\in B:(x,y)\in C\}$ for $x\in A$.
Then, $\chi_C(x,y)=\chi_{D_x}(y)$.
Suppose $x\in A$ and $\mathbf{U}\int_B\chi_C(x,y)dy=0$.
Then, $\mathbf{U}\int_B\chi_{D_x}(y)\,dy=\inf\{U(\chi_{D_x},P_B)\}=0$.
So, for an arbitrary positive real number $\varepsilon$, there is a partition $P_B$ of $B$ such that $U(\chi_{D_x},P_B)<\varepsilon$.
So, $D_x$ has content $0$.
So, $x\in A-A'$.
So, $A'\subset\{x\in A:\mathbf{U}\int_B\chi_C(x,y)dy\neq 0\}$.
So, $A'$ has measure $0$.

Comment: This isn't a "here's my proof, check it for me" site. The `solution-verification` tag explicitly notes that you must identify a *specific* step that you are unsure about, and *explicitly* explain why that is the case. Otherwise, posting an entire proof seeking simple verification or feedback is "too broad" and off-topic.